# Cannot access [Authorize] controllers with cookie authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 and Cookie authentication to login.
I saw the cookie generated as the picture below, but I still cannot access [Authorize] controllers.

This is my code in Startup.cs
ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax;
});
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
         {
              options.Cookie.Name = "SRLoginCookie";
              options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
              options.LoginPath = new PathString("/users/login");
              options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
              options.SlidingExpiration = false;
          });
services.PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
          options =>
          {
               options.LoginPath = "/users/login";
          });
```

Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Login code

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromForm]LoginRequest model)
{
       var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
       identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, model.Email));
       ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

       await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                        principal);
       //if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
              return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

[image]
The cookie was generated, but can't access home/index as you see. What is my problem? Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution after posting this question for a while.
Just need `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` instead of `[Authorize]`, everthing solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };

        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                // get token from cookie
                if (context.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("SRLoginCookie"))
                {
                    context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["SRLoginCookie"];
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
```